# how can I capture the starting of the shake?

Tags: iphone, shake

i have implemented the

```
 - (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

to capture the shake when some one ends the shaking of iPhone, but I need to determine the start of shake, how can o do this?

Comment: How do you know it's a shake at the start of the shake? At that point, it's just an unknown movement.

Comment: @ceejayoz, you don't know at the time, but you still have to notice the beginning of a motion event that could become a shake. It's like a double-click: you can't know that it's a double-click when it starts, but if you don't look at every click that could begin a double-click, you'll never recognize any double-clicks at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try reading this :

http://devinsheaven.com/cocoa-touch-tutorial-receiving-using-the-shake-api-for-iphone-os-3/

Answer (score 2):

`- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {`